# Convert Magick Command to Magick.Net Code

Tags: imagemagick, magick.net, imagemagick.net

I want to convert command below to Magick.Net Code.

```
convert sunset_lake.png \
\( -background none -pointsize 24 -fill white label:"TESTING" -rotate 20 -write mpr:tile +delete \) \
\( +clone -tile mpr:tile -draw "color 0,0 reset" \) \
-compose over -composite sunset_lake_tile_text.png
```

I am not sure what is the corresponding code for `-write mpr:tile +delete` and `mpr:tile -draw "color 0,0 reset"`.

Any help would be appreciated.